# How to use register expression with visual selection?

Tags: key-bindings, visual-mode, expression-register

I have this key map in my Vim configuration:

```
nmap <leader>rn :%s/\<<C-r><C-w>\>/
```

But for this code from php I have a problem.

```
$text=$home_intro['text'];
```

Because, if cursor is on start of the word ** text **, then this map changes `$text`, not text.

I think to do in this way, from start of the text word, press `ve`, visual to the end of word, and then press map to replace.

Yes, and the second question, how to replace just on this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would introduce a v mapping:

```
vnoremap <leader>rn "zy:%s/<C-r>z/
```

- `"zy` copy the selection in the `z` register.
- `<C-r>z` paste the `z` register.

If you want to get rid of the all file replacement drop the `%`.

```
vnoremap <leader>rn "zy:s/<C-r>z/
```

Comment: Thank you, i will remember)) 
Cool!!!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) If it solves your problem consider accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons.  It allow the question to rest  :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you've already visually selected the word, pressing `s` or `c` will let you start changing it. The change is dot-repeatable.

If you wanted to be able to repeat the change (like `&` with `:substitute`), you have a few options:

- search the word and `cgn`. Then `.` repeats on the next occurrence, or `n` to navigate so you can skip occurrences.
- do a global substitute with confirmation (`:%substitute/pat/repl/gc`) so you can avoid the `$test`, for example.
- load occurrences into a quickfix (or location list) with `:[l]vimgrep /word/ %`; you can filter the list with `:Cfilter` from the builtin `cfilter` plugin (`:help :Cfilter`) before running `:cdo <command to make change>`. It is harder to deal with duplicates on one line this way, though, and `:vimgrep` operates on files (not buffers).